# PHP: creating HTML table from nested array (json) but getting results AND "invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, nested

I am trying to create a HTML table from an array that is obtained through api/json.

It's a nested array (the actual data is nested within the session)

```
Array
(
[sessid] => -hnkGi-k1rgwhnymkcScR0bom-RRKURn2S1pgMZoBX4
[status] => 0
[players] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Chris
                [last_name] => Clausing
                [pdga_number] => 31635
                [rating] => 930
                [year] => 2014
                [class] => A
                [gender] => M
                [bracket] => Open
                [country] => NL
                [state_prov] => 
                [tournaments] => 11
                [rating_rounds_used] => 36
                [points] => 998
                [prize] => 0.00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Uwe Walter
                [last_name] => Schlueter
                [pdga_number] => 37788
                [rating] => 902
                [year] => 2014
                [class] => A
                [gender] => M
                [bracket] => Master
                [country] => NL
                [state_prov] => 
                [tournaments] => 12
                [rating_rounds_used] => 33
                [points] => 970
                [prize] => 0.00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Mark
                [last_name] => Steenhuis
                [pdga_number] => 50574
                [rating] => 859
                [year] => 2014
                [class] => A
                [gender] => M
                [bracket] => Master
                [country] => NL
                [state_prov] => 
                [tournaments] => 12
                [rating_rounds_used] => 28
                [points] => 678
                [prize] => 0.00
            )
      )
)
```

And the warning mesages:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/surrealm/dvh/player_statistics.php on line 103

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/surrealm/dvh/player_statistics.php on line 103
```

See http://vliegende-hollander.com/player_statistics.php?year=2014&class=A&gender=M&country=NL

As you can see i can extract the desired data, and create the HTML table from it.
But, I can not get rid of the two error messages.

If i take away one of the foreach() i only get first character of first value only (in this case, the first character of the sessid).

The actual bit of PHP i'm using to create the table is:

```
<?

if (is_array($player)) {
 foreach($player as $key){
  foreach($key as $k){             // <- this is line 103
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$k['pdga_number']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$k['first_name']." ".$k['last_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$k['country']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$k['rating']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Can anyone help me clean up this code, so i get rid of the two warnings?

I'm not a full-time programmer, so it's probably just my not fully understanding the foreach() function.
I usually extract and display data using MySQL, and while() loops instead.

Comment: Can we see the `$player` array?

Comment: It's visible at the URL http://vliegende-hollander.com/player_statistics.php?year=2014&class=A&gender=M&country=NL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that the `$key` variable that you passed into the for each isn't an array. For this to work the `player` array would have to have arrays within it (i.e. be a multidimensional array), so the second `foreach` can iterate through it.

If your player array doesn't have arrays within it, then you only need **one** `foreach` to loop through and then you can access the data using the index (i.e. `$key['pdga_number']` instead of `$k['pdga_number']`).

For me to fully help though, I would need to know the contents of the `$player` array.

**EDIT**

I've just seen the example given, try doing a second `if(is_array($key)` before calling the second foreach, i.e.

```
if (is_array($player)) {
    foreach($player as $key){
        if(is_array($key)){
            foreach($key as $k){             // <- this is line 103
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$k['pdga_number']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$k['first_name']." ".$k['last_name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$k['country']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$k['rating']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just added array and warning messages to original post.

Comment: Assuming it is one array, and using only one foreach() loop, i get an "illegal string offset" warning for each for each variable i'm calling, AND in the table, it displays the first character of the first variable it sees (the first character of the sessid)

Comment: I've just updated my post with a possible answer. Try adding the second `is_array($key)` and let me know the results please?

Comment: Thank you, that worked!!!
I don't understand WHY it works like that, but it works

Comment: No worries, it's because you're making sure the `$key` is an array before iterating over it using a for each. Could you mark it as the answer if you believe it is - thanks!